# JSF templating breaks XML Namespace "no taglibrary exists"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I am experiencing an issue where JSF renders a warning when loading a page:

> Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/
>   declared with prefix li but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.

This works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:body>
    <f:view>
        <ul>
            <li>Test</li>
        </ul>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

However...once I move the UL tag into an include file it fails:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:body>
    <f:view>
        <ui:include src="/include/test.xhtml"></ui:include>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

with test.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the `xhtml` part of your `xmlns`?

Comment: @mabi not sure what you mean...

Comment: Your `test.xhtml` needs to say `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`, it's missing the last `xhtml` bit. Is this a c&p error?